# How to run spark application written in scala in CDH5.4

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I'm using CDH 5.4, I wrote my fisrst scala program, I built a jar, and  put my input file into Hdfs, but I didn't find yet how to run the application. Is it in Hue like running a map reduce Job, or by a spark submit in a shell ? I found that there is spark Igniter in Hue but the version that I'm using don't have this application.

Comment: No one have an idea :(

Comment: About Hue, currently you would need the Notebook application and use a Jar snippet http://gethue.com/new-notebook-application-for-spark-sql/ or even simpler, use the new Spark Action of Oozie in Hue http://gethue.com/new-apache-oozie-workflow-coordinator-bundle-editors/. If the CLI is ok, spark-submit would be easy too.